# MAZE how many routes are possible

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, problem-solving

[image]

What I did:

1. convert this to a graph with nodes representing rooms and edges representing the pathway possible
2. Figure out how many edges were leaving each node minus one since you can't go back (e.g node *V* would have a value of 2) except obv for Q
3. multiply all together (equaling to 2^8)

Is this right? I know this method might be dumb for a problem for 12-year-olds but im stupid. Any help on how to actually solve this efficiently/improvements is appreciated.

Comment: Your attempt doesn't sound stupid at all.  Certainly, some sort of tree seems called for.  I'm not sure what it is you multiplied, and I don't see how to do it that way.  Can you explain what you did in more detail, please?

Comment: @saulspatz Here is my graph that I made, pretty sure the graph is right with all the connections and everything. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBo6W.jpg

Comment: Your graph is correct, or at least, it's the same graph that I drew.  I don't think that the multiplication you did is justified, though.  We are asked to count all simple paths between vertices $U$ and $Q$, and so far as I know, there is no simple algorithm for this.  So far as I know, the only way to do it is by a brute-force enumeration of all the paths.  That's the only answer I found surfing the Web, also.  I'll se what answer I come up with, but it will be a while before you hear from me again.  You've done good work so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a little python script to find all the simple paths in the graph from $U$ to $Q$.  It found $21$ such paths.

Here's the script:

```
from collections import defaultdict

adjacent = defaultdict(str)
adjacent['q'] = 'rsx'
adjacent['r'] = 'qst'
adjacent['s']= 'qrw'
adjacent['t']= 'ruv'
adjacent['u']= 'ty'
adjacent['v']= 'twy'
adjacent['w']= 'svx'
adjacent['x']= 'qwz'
adjacent['y']=  'uvz'
adjacent['z']= 'xy'

queue = ['u']
paths = []
while queue:
    path = queue.pop(0)
    if path.endswith('q'):
        paths.append(path)
    else:
        for room in adjacent[path[-1]]:
            if room in path: continue
            queue.append(path+room)
print(f'{len(paths)} simple paths found')
for path in paths:
    print(path.upper())
```

and here is the output:

```
21 simple paths found
UTRQ
UTRSQ
UYZXQ
UTVWSQ
UTVWXQ
UYVTRQ
UYVWSQ
UYVWXQ
UTRSWXQ
UTVWSRQ
UTVYZXQ
UYVTRSQ
UYVWSRQ
UYZXWSQ
UYZXWSRQ
UTVYZXWSQ
UYVTRSWXQ
UYZXWVTRQ
UTRSWVYZXQ
UTVYZXWSRQ
UYZXWVTRSQ
```

The idea of the program is very simple, and you can carry it out by hand for a program this small.  Make a list of all the partial paths encountered so far.  (This is called `queue` in the program.)  Initially, the only path on the list is $U$.  Now so long as there are partial paths on the list, do the following:

1. Remove the first path from the list.
2. For each room adjacent to the last room on the path:

   - If the room is $Q$, add it to the path and record the augmented path as a complete path.
   - If the room is already on the path, do nothing
   - Otherwise, add the room to the path, and put the augmented path back on the end of the list.

Comment: lmaoooo def not 256. Thanks for your script but QQ, wdym by simple paths?

Comment: A simple path is a path that never goes through the same vertex twice.

Comment: ah shot homie, thats what I was trying to do with my now in retrospect dumb way with the edges -1 stuff.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check mark, so that it leaves the unanswered queue.